# Dynamically showed div disappears on AJAX postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am showing one hidden panel with JQUERY where user can login. This div is is in update panel because I don't want it to be closed unless the login is successful. But on Ajax postback it always disappears. Looks like the initial stylesheet always loads after the partial postback.

Any help please..

here is the HTML code

```
<div align="center">

                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="show popup" />


    </div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upLogin" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="BlockPage">
                <div id="loginSignup">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Post" />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: HI... Thanks for your time. I have updated my question with html code. On the btnLogin click I am just displaying time in lblMsg.